# SQL Query multiple rows into one, if criteria met

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am a novice at this, nor is this my data. We are trying to pull multiple records into one record for query results.

To simplify the tables and amount of data, the following two tables should be sufficient:

Table 1

```
PRVDR_NUM | RPT_REC_NUM  
013          1234
014          4567
```

Table 2

```
RPT_REC_NUM |  WKSHT_CD | LINE_NUM | ITM_VAL_NUM
1234             f1         3           30
1234             f1         9           3
1234             e2       100           100
4567             f1         3           20
4567             f1         9           8
4567             e2       100           100
```

The first part is to get all records where the ITM_NUM_CAL is between 25 and 50 for WKSHT_CD f1 and LINE_NUM 3, that ITM_NUM_VAL is revenue.

```
SELECT      r.PRVDR_NUM as Provider, 
            r.RPT_REC_NUM as 'Report Record', 
            n.ITM_VAL_NUM as Revenue

FROM        Table 1 r
        left outer join Table 2 n on 
        r.RPT_REC_NUM = n.RPT_REC_NUM

WHERE (n.WKSHT_CD = 'f1') and (n.LINE_NUM = '3')
        and (n.ITM_VAL_NUM > 25) and (n.ITM_VAL_NUM < 50)
        and left(r.PRVDR_NUM, 2) in ('01','04','11','18','25','26','34','44','49')
```

So our results are:

```
Provider |  Report Record | Revenue 
 013           1234         30
```

But we also want to be able to pull the corresponding ITM_VAL_NUM for WKSHT_CD f1 and LINE_NUM 9, which we'll call cost.

So the results should be:

```
Provider |  Report Record | Revenue | Cost
 013           1234          30         3
```

Much thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

I believe this is the final query I was looking for after some maneuvering and the addition of a new variable, CLMN_NUM, which is another column in table2.

```
SELECT r.PRVDR_NUM as Provider, 
       r.RPT_REC_NUM as 'Report Record', 
       n.ITM_VAL_NUM as Revenue,
       n2.ITM_VAL_NUM as 'Cost',
       n3.ITM_VAL_NUM as 'Visits'

FROM table1 r
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 n on r.RPT_REC_NUM = n.RPT_REC_NUM
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 n2 on n.WKSHT_CD = n2.WKSHT_CD
    and n.RPT_REC_NUM = n2.RPT_REC_NUM and n2.LINE_NUM = 9
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 n3 on r.RPT_REC_NUM = n3.RPT_REC_NUM 
    and n3.WKSHT_CD = 'e2' and n3.LINE_NUM = 100 and n3.CLMN_NUM = xxxx  

WHERE (n.WKSHT_CD = 'f1') 
AND (n.LINE_NUM = '3')
AND (n.ITM_VAL_NUM > 25) 
AND (n.ITM_VAL_NUM < 50)
AND left(r.PRVDR_NUM, 2) in ('01','04','11','18','25','26','34','44','49')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple ways:

**Subquery**

```
SELECT r.PRVDR_NUM as Provider, 
       r.RPT_REC_NUM as 'Report Record', 
       n.ITM_VAL_NUM as Revenue
       (SELECT ITM_VAL_NUM 
        FROM Table2 
        WHERE WKSHT_CD = n.WKSHT_CD 
        AND LINE_NUM = 9) AS Cost
FROM Table1 r
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 n on r.RPT_REC_NUM = n.RPT_REC_NUM
WHERE (n.WKSHT_CD = 'f1') 
AND (n.LINE_NUM = '3')
AND (n.ITM_VAL_NUM > 25) 
AND (n.ITM_VAL_NUM < 50)
AND left(r.PRVDR_NUM, 2) in ('01','04','11','18','25','26','34','44','49')
```

**Another JOIN**

```
SELECT r.PRVDR_NUM as Provider, 
       r.RPT_REC_NUM as 'Report Record', 
       n.ITM_VAL_NUM as Revenue
       n2.Cost
FROM Table1 r
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 n on r.RPT_REC_NUM = n.RPT_REC_NUM
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 n2 on n.WKSHT_CD = n2.WKSHT_CD
        AND LINE_NUM = 9
WHERE (n.WKSHT_CD = 'f1') 
AND (n.LINE_NUM = '3')
AND (n.ITM_VAL_NUM > 25) 
AND (n.ITM_VAL_NUM < 50)
AND left(r.PRVDR_NUM, 2) in ('01','04','11','18','25','26','34','44','49')
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses when I try your subquery solution I get a message for more than 1 value. When I try your JOIN solution after some modification I get it to work but end up with way too many rows, as if it pulled all the cost.

Comment: On both of these it would be because of the data, and I assume you only provide a sampling. You would need to add conditions to ensure only 1 record would return.

Comment: Thanks for your help Dustin, I have edited my post with some modification and additions, would this appear to be alright?

Comment: yes, although I would think some of this data could be normalized into a better structure to help organize this data more efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

You can by doing a CASE/WHEN on your columns in question, but allowing BOTH values of LINE_NUM in your where too...  Using the COALESCE will prevent NULL values in case no records for one side, the other or both for revenue/costs respectively.  You could just use the same consideration for any other "LINE_NUM" values you wanted to include too.

```
SELECT
      r.PRVDR_NUM as Provider,
      r.RPT_REC_NUM as 'Report Record',
      COALESCE( CASE WHEN n.LINE_NUM = 3 THEN n.ITM_VAL_NUM ELSE 0 END, 0 ) as Revenue,
      COALESCE( CASE WHEN n.LINE_NUM = 9 THEN n.ITM_VAL_NUM ELSE 0 END, 0 ) as Costs
   from
      Table_1 r
         left join Table_2 n
            on r.RPT_REC_NUM = n.RPT_REC_NUM
            AND n.WKSHT_CD = 'f1'
            AND n.LINE_NUM in ( '3', '9')
            AND n.ITM_VAL_NUM between 25 and 50
   where
      left(r.PRVDR_NUM, 2) in ('01','04','11','18','25','26','34','44','49')
```

Comment: I've attempted this and tried some modifications but I come with zeros every time in both fields.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  Provider        = r.PRVDR_NUM,
  [Report Record] = r.RPT_REC_NUM,
  Revenue         = MIN(CASE n.LINE_NUM WHEN '3' THEN n.ITM_VAL_NUM),
  Cost            = MIN(CASE n.LINE_NUM WHEN '9' THEN n.ITM_VAL_NUM)
FROM Table1 r
  INNER JOIN Table2 n ON r.RPT_REC_NUM = n.RPT_REC_NUM
WHERE n.WKSHT_CD = 'f1' AND n.LINE_NUM IN ('3', '9')
  AND n.ITM_VAL_NUM > 25 AND n.ITM_VAL_NUM < 50
  AND LEFT(r.PRVDR_NUM, 2) IN ('01','04','11','18','25','26','34','44','49')
GROUP BY
  r.PRVDR_NUM,
  r.RPT_REC_NUM
```